# Microtype warnings (~100) with fontsetup (NewComputerModern)

Tags: microtype, luaotfload, newcomputermodern, fontsetup

I have been using the `microtype` package together with the `fontsetup` package.
The document seems to compile normally. Protrusion and expansion also seem to be working, but I usually get around 100 warnings from microtype.

I would just ignore the warnings, but it is really annoying if you are trying to debug a compile error and the actual mistakes gets lost in the multitude of errors and warnings.

What do these warnings actually mean? Is there a way to disable the warnings? (Sorry, I am not too versed in `microtype`).

I would really appreciate a answer, as it would make it easier for debugging erroneous code.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage[default]{fontsetup}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[math]{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

I tried using the Hints and Caveats provided in manual, but maybe I did sth wrong there. I tried

```
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{NewCMRoman}{LatinModernRoman}
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{NCM-default}{TU-basic}
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{NewCM10-Book}{TU-basic}
\DeclareMicrotypeAlias{NCM-TU}{TU-empty}
```

Error list:

```
Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FBC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FCC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FFC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/a.end'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/e.end'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/k.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/r.end'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/m.end'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/n.end'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FBC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FCC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FFC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/a.end'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/e.end'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/k.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/r.end'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/m.end'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/n.end'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list
(microtype)                `NCM-TU'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FBC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F88.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F89.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8A.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8B.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8C.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8D.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8E.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8F.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FCC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F98.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F99.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9A.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9B.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9C.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9D.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9E.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9F.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FFC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FA8.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FA9.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAA.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAB.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAD.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAE.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAF.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FBC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F88.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F89.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8A.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8B.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8C.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8D.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8E.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8F.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FCC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F98.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F99.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9A.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9B.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9C.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9D.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9E.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9F.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FFC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FA8.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FA9.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAA.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAB.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAD.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAE.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAF.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FBC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F88.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F89.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8A.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8B.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8C.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8D.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8E.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F8F.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FCC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F98.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F99.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9A.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9B.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9C.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9D.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9E.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1F9F.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FFC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FA8.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FA9.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAA.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAB.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAC.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAD.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAE.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.


Package microtype Warning: Unknown slot number of character
(microtype)                `/uni1FAF.alt'
(microtype)                in font encoding `TU' in protrusion list 
(microtype)                `NCM-default'.
```

Comment: This is a glitch in `luaotfload`, which currently doesn't recognise all slot names. It has been [fixed in the development version](https://github.com/latex3/luaotfload/issues/198). Until the next `luaotfload` release, you could suppress the warnings with `\usepackage[verbose=silent]{microtype}`.

Comment: @Robert Ok thx. So I either get the development version off of GitHub or wait for the release and use `[verbose=silent]` for `microtype` at the moment, right?

Comment: that's right...